# Adding elements to existing div (PHP/JS)

Tags: php, jquery, html, css

I have an existing div and I want to add some new data (5 spans) to this existing div. The method I was using makes the following GUI

[image]

I want it to display the search results in existing div (in black translucent region). My HTML Code is

```
<title>Search your Friends</title>
<body>
<div class="title">
    GTBIT's Almuni Diary
</div>

<div class="main">
    <form id="myForm" method="POST">
        <input placeholder="Enter some text to search"type="text" class="name" name="query">
        <br>
        <span class="searchby">Search Criteria</span>
        <select name="criteria">
            <option value="name" selected="selected">Search by Name</option>
            <option value="enrno">Search by Enrollment No.</option>
            <option value="email">Search by Email ID</option>
            <option value="phno">Search by Phone No.</option>
        </select>
        <br>
        <input type="button" class="search" value="Search">
    </form>
    <div class="sr">
        Search Results
    </div>
    <div class="dynamicData">
        <div class="header">
            <span class="heading">Name</span>
            <span class="heading">Email ID</span>
            <span class="heading">Enrollment No.</span>
            <span class="heading">Nickname</span>
            <span class="heading">Batch</span>
        </div>
        <div class='dataDiv'>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

CSS :

```
body
{
    font-family: "source sans pro";
    font-size: 20px;
    background-image: url("../images/searchbg.jpg");
    background-size: 100% 100%;
    background-attachment: fixed;
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
}

.title
{
    display: none; 
    color: #03C9A9;
    background-color: rgba(0,0,0,0.8);
    padding: 5px;
    font-weight: 500;
    font-size: 54px;
    height: 90px;
    text-align: center;
}

.main
{
    display: none;
    width: 90%;
    margin: 0 auto;
    margin-top: 20px;
    background-color: rgba(0,0,0,0.5);
    padding: 20px;
}

.searchby, input, select
{
    color: white;
    font-family: inherit;
    font-size: 28px;
    display: inline-block;
}
.name
{
    color: black;
    width: 80%;
}
.searchby
{
    margin-top: 40px;
}
select
{
    border: 0px solid white;
    margin-left: 30px;
    margin-right: 30px;
    color: black;
    font-size: 22px;
}
.search
{
    background-color: rgba(0,0,0,0.8);
    color: #03C9A9;
    margin: 0 auto;
    margin-top: 30px;
    padding: 5px;
    display: block;
    border: 0px solid white;
    cursor: pointer;
    font-size: 32px;
}
.name
{
    margin-left: 10px;
    border: 0px solid white;
}

.sr
{
    margin-top: 75px;
    font-family: inherit;
    font-size: 32px;
    width: 100%;
    text-align: center;
    background-color: rgba(0,0,0,0.8);
    color: #03C9A9;
    margin-bottom: 50px;
}

.dynamicData
{
    width: 98%;
    margin-left: 10px;
    padding: 2px;
    background-color: rgba(0,0,0,0.3);
}

.header
{
    padding: 5px;
    width: 90%;
    text-align: center;
    padding: 5px 0px 5px 0px;
    margin: 0 auto;
}
.heading
{
    background-color: #03C9A9;
    color: white;
    font-family: inherit;
    font-size: 24px;
    height: 30px;
    width: 202px;
    display: inline-block;
    margin-bottom: 10px;
}

.dataDiv
{
    padding: 2px;
    width: 90%;
    text-align: center;
    margin: 0 auto;
}

.data
{
    font-family: inherit;
    font-size: 24px;
    height: 30px;
    width: 202px;
    display: inline-block;
    margin-bottom: 5px;
    color: black;
    background-color: rgba(255,255,255,0.75);
}
```

PHP Script responsible for adding (after getting data form database)

```
while($stmt->fetch())
{
    echo "<br>
    <span class='data ndata'>$nm</span>
    <span class='data emaildata'>$em</span>
    <span class='data enrnodata'>$eno</span>
    <span class='data nicknamedata'>$nn</span>
    <span class='data batchdata'>$bt</span>";
}
```

Comment: We will need the js to help you out.

Comment: I am using PHP to add data. JQuery has methods called 'append' to append data to existing div but isn't working. Is there any PHP way of doing this ?

Comment: question is vague about when you want these added...after page is already rendered in browser, or while it is being created at server? What code didn't work when using `jQuery.append()`?

Comment: PHP only sends data back from the server to the browser, We will need your javascript to help you in any way. We want to help, but we'd rather help someone who provides us all the required code (HTML, JS, PHP).

Comment: while it is being created at the server. After taking the search query I refresh the page.

Comment: ok ...so which Jquery method should be used to append this data ?

Comment: thanks guyz, somehow I have managed to do this my mixing a bit of HTML and PHP :p